# Remove local Docker images on macOS

Tags: image, macos, docker, local

I'm using Docker for Mac and for saving disk space I want to get rid of some unused local images. As far as I know the local files are stored in ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker.

But even if I remove all images and containers from docker the folder keeps it's size of some GB and not a single byte is released. The only option is to remove the com.docker.docker folder completely but this makes only sense if you want to remove all the data and not only the unused images. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with `docker image rm`?

Comment: As I mentioned it correctly removes the image from the cli but the com.docker.docker folder doesn't shrink as expected. It's not about removing the containers / images but releasing disk space accordingly.

Comment: @Henry has the answer everyone is looking for. `docker image rm IMAGEID -f` to forcibly delete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is going on here is that your docker for mac application is really running a virtual machine. That virtual machine has its own disk, which is what that qcow2 file is. That disk gets lazily allocated and won't take up all it space all at once. Once the space is used inside the vm, then the disk will grow on the host.

The disk image will grow until it reaches the size of the disk. Just because a file gets deleted inside the vm, that will not cause the disk image on the host to shrink again.

There is a possible solution to shrink your disk image: https://forums.docker.com/t/where-does-docker-keep-images-containers-so-i-can-better-track-my-disk-usage/8370/7

I have seen a few folks use this trick with some success.

Comment: Thanks for your explanination that made some things more understandable. So even if it's not a solution at all (and obviously there isn't a 'real solution' at this time) it should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo docker system prune -af
```

Just simple put the command given above.
It will delete all the image automatically.

Answer (score 10):

To remove all unused images, use [`docker images prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/).

There's also another way to remove all unused image (dangling): `docker rmi $(docker images -aq --filter dangling=true)`

To remove images you do no need, use [`docker rmi <image>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/). You may use multiple images, eg. `docker rmi abcdef ghijkl`, where `abcdef` and `ghijkl` are image hashes.

If this does not help immediately, try restarting your docker service (`sudo service docker restart`). In some cases images/containers are only marked as `deleted` and are not removed. But they are after restart.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Sadly none of them solved my problem. `docker rmi $(docker images -aq --filter dangling=true)` returns `"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument(s).` and `docker images prune` returns an empty images list. `sudo service docker restart` gives me a `sudo: service: command not found` in the terminal so I restarted the Docker app several times as well as used the restart button  - but my Finder tells me 6,39 GB folder size before and after all these tries.

Comment: I'm not sure how mac works, so maybe `service` is not the right command. It works in *nix, so I thought it would work on mac too, since it's *nix. Try removing unused images manually

Answer (score 6):

List your images with:

`docker images`

Delete a single image with:

`docker rmi image_id`